# How can I connect a local delta lake with talend for data profiling purpose?

Tags: pyspark, talend, delta-lake, data-profiling

As I am new to talend, I am trying to connect my local delta lake with talend to do some data profiling on it.

Comment: and what problem are you having?

Comment: As I am new to it I don't know how to begin with it, means I have create a local delta lake with spark so what's next?

Comment: So you have a delta lake built on some storage platform - what is that platform? So have you looked in the Talend documentation about how to connect to that storage platform?

Comment: I simply made a spark data-frame, and stored it locally on my PC using format as delta, so they are being saved as parquet files. @NickW

Comment: So you connect Talend to your parquet file(s) - what is the question/issue?

Comment: I typed `talend parquet input` into gppgle and got this https://help.talend.com/r/en-US/8.0/parquet/tfileinputparquet. Why don't you try this and come back with a specific problem.

Comment: Thanks Nick, surely with check it out!